# How To Close a UserForm Properly in Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I need to close a UserForm from a procedure that is inside the general module. The following code is just a test. I cannot use Me once that I am out of the form module.

```
Private Sub btnCancel_Click()        
    On Error GoTo TreatError

    Dim screen As Object

    Set screen = UserForms.Add(Me.Name)
    Unload screen
Leave:
    Set screen = Nothing
    Exit Sub
TreatError:
    GoTo Leave
End Sub
```

What's missing in this code? When I press the Cancel button, nothing happens, well, the form still keeps loaded. This UserForm is ShowModal True.

thanks in advance.

Ok Pᴇʜ. Here you are:

```
Public Sub EditarCombo(nomeColuna As String, itemCombobox As Variant, novoValor As Variant)
    On Error GoTo TratarErro
    
    Dim planilha As Worksheet
    Dim planRamais As Worksheet
    Dim tela As UserForm
    
    If ((itemCombobox & "") <> "") Then
        If ((Trim(novoValor) & "") <> "") Then
            If (itemCombobox <> Trim(novoValor)) Then
                Set planilha = Worksheets("CombosRamais")
                Set planRamais = Worksheets("Ramais")
                
                EditarNaColuna planilha, nomeColuna, itemCombobox, novoValor
                ExcluirDuplicadasNaColuna planilha, nomeColuna, novoValor
                OrdemarColuna planilha, nomeColuna, True
                RedefinirAreaColuna planilha, planRamais, nomeColuna
                
                EditarNaColuna planRamais, nomeColuna, itemCombobox, novoValor
            Else
                MsgBox "Você deve digitar um novo valor para o item escolhido.", vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "Editar Item"
                GoTo Sair
            End If
        Else
            MsgBox "O campo de novo valor está vazio.", vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "Editar Item"
            GoTo Sair
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox "Escolha um item na lista para ser editado.", vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "Editar Item"
        GoTo Sair
    End If
    
    Set tela = UserForms.Add(Replace(nomeColuna, "Col", "frmEditar"))
    Unload tela
Sair:
    Set tela = Nothing
    Set planilha = Nothing
    Set planRamais = Nothing
    Exit Sub
TratarErro:
    GoTo Sair
End Sub
```

Comment: What do you expect `Me` to be? `Me` does not exist in a module. Where is this procedure `btnCancel_Click` located? Can you provide a [mcve]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment to FunThomas' answer you would like to have a function like that

```
Public Function UnLoadFrm(formName As String) 
    Dim frm As Object

    For Each frm In VBA.UserForms
        If frm.Name = formName Then
            Unload frm
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next frm

End Function
```

Be careful when using it as it is case sensitive. It might also be a good idea to use `frm.Hide` instead of `Unload frm` but then you should also rename the function.

Comment: I was very reluctant to use the above loop because it is a lot of code for one simple thing that could be done in one line of code in Access. But, if it is the best way (because it is the only one), who am I to say something against it? It is already working and I thank you all for the prompt help and attention paid.

Answer (score 0):

Don't unload forms - just hide them.
From the form itself, use `Me.Hide`.

If you want to hide the form within module code, use `UserForm1.Hide`.

Destroying a form, especially in the wrong moment, can lead to surprising behavior that is really hard to understand. If you want to know more, read about "Default Instances". Hiding a form simply hides it from the screen so that it is not visible for the moment, but stays in memory.

**Update**
My answer was mainly to point out that you shoudn't destroy a form. If the subroutine is called from different forms and you pass the control (eg comboBox) as parameter, you can use the `Parent`-property to get the form object and hide it:

```
Public Sub EditarCombo(nomeColuna As String, itemCombobox As Control, novoValor As Variant)
    (...)
    itemCombobox.Parent.Hide
    (...)
End Sub
```

Comment: It doesn't work either. In this case, it causes error 402.

Comment: Do I understand it correctly that **a)** the routine `EditarCombo` is called from different forms and should close the form that was calling it and **b)** that the parameter `itemCombobox` is a combobox (control) of that form?

Comment: **a)** `EditarCombo` is called from the same UserForm that I want to Unload. **b)** `itemCombobox` is a combobox from this UserForm. it contains the old value of the combobox that will be replaced by `novoValor` parameter _(new value)_.

Comment: I need something like this: `Unload UserForms("frmEditarCompetencia")`.